# Async iterator in Javascript

Tags: javascript, iterator, async-await, generator, ecmascript-2018

I'm looking for the best way to make an async iterator in Javascript. I'm already using generators and async/await functions, but I can't find a way to achieve the so-called for-await-of loop without using the latest Node.js release (10.x).

The problem is the following :

I'm fetching large amount of data from an API and I need to scroll the content of it. I don't want to store all the content in an array, as it would explode in RAM.

I know how to do that using streams, but it would be cooler (to my point of view)  to do it using generators.

Thanks for your help,

Best regards,

-- 
Corentin

Comment: [async iterators](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-async-iteration) are a new feature that is expected to be introduced in 2018. They should work in current chrome/FF/node and related already, but only in state-of-the-art versions, as you noticed.

Comment: If the amount of data explodes RAM, you won't be able to render it on a scrollable page to begin with, so why fetch so much in one go?

Comment: Compile your code to es5 using [babel](https://babeljs.io/)

Comment: "*I can't find a way to achieve this without using the latest Node.js release*" - then just use the latest release, is that a problem?

Comment: Thanks for your comments, guys!

ASDFGerte & Shilly: I'm not planning to use that on the frontend, only on the backend. I didn't say I was going to display the information, just go through it.

Santhosh, I know that I can compile the code to ES5, basically I know every alternative I have, I was asking the question because I think it's way better not to use Babel when you don't need to (it has a noticeable impact on performance)

Bergi, as far as I know, async iterators are experimental in the latest Node release, and this is not a LTS one, so I cannot use it in production.

Comment: @Corentin the `for await of` syntax will not be available in previous versions of node, but you could still use streams in an older version. Also you could try my framework [`scramjet`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scramjet) - it uses async operations node v8.x and the API is quite nice for such cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Async iterators are not available in node.js below v10, but there are some pretty good ways to consume a stream asynchronously without iterators, for example with [`scramjet`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scramjet):

```
const stream = DataStream.from(someNodeObjectStream);
await (async () => {
    while (let data = await stream.whenRead()) {
        doSomethingWith(data);
    }
})();
```

This is more or less the syntactic sugar you get from async iterators.